# 500 error on binary compiled CGI script after migration to new servers

Tags: linux, apache, cgi

I recently migrated to a new hosting company. I am pretty new to linux and apache as far as configuration is involved. I can't execute a binary CGI script on the new server. I get a 500 server misconfiguration when trying to execute the script and in the erro log i get:
"End of script output before headers"
Our old server used the programming language HTML OS by aestiva which uses binary compiled CGI scripts to operate. Things I have tried:

1. Permissions - all permissions are set to 755, other simple cgi scripts run fine with the same permissions
2. writing a simple GCI sript - executes just fine even in the same directory
3. disabling and enabling selinux
4. running the script from command line i get this error "Unrecognized character \x7F in column 1 at asetup476.cgi line 1"

Anyways, here are the specs:

**OLD SERVER**
easy Apache 3 2.4.25(Unix)
perl v5.10.1

**NEW SERVER**
easy Apache 4 2.4.29(cPanel)
perl v5.10.1

the file structures are completely different between easy Apache 3 and 4 so are the httpd.conf files so copying over the conf files probably wont work. My hosting provider asks me to make sure the files are uploaded with ASCII but this is a binary compiled file so that will render it unusable. I am new to this so I am sorry if there is not enough info, I will provide whatever you need if you are attempting to help. Any help is very much appreciated!
here is the cgi script I am trying to run:
[file](http://www.htmlos.org/pages/htmlos/5125.16.775090428419977898)

**EDIT**
possible cause, I have found out that my old server supports 32 bit CGI executable and my new server possibly does not. command line test:

```
readelf -h $(which init) | grep "Class"
```

returned:

```
Class:                             ELF64
```

I hope this sheds some light, anyone know how to add 32 bit support to CentOS linux?

**SOLVED**
enabling 32 bit support for centOS linux did the trick:

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

Comment: First, try `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);`  in scripts.

Comment: If it's a compiled file, what does Perl have to do with it?

Comment: You'll probably need to recompile any binaries for the OS on the new servers

Comment: @PinkTux - if this a binary compiled file, can I add that without messing up the script?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I am using a recompiled binary installation script to try and install HTML OS on the new server, so it's most likely something with the configuration

Comment: @simbabque I don't know, are compiled scripts not executed with perl? I am new to all of this, so I am trying

Comment: No, that's why it's compiled. It might be that it was a Perl script that was compiled using PAR, but we don't know. Can you try to find more information?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question, as it's about a binary, not about a Perl script with CGI.pm.

Comment: @simbabque I am not sure what it was compiled with, it is an old programming language called HTML OS. the link i put will take you right to the file and the install instructions

Comment: this one: http://www.htmlos.org/pages/htmlos/website/index.html?

Comment: @simbabque yes that site has the linux script

Comment: It seems to be proprietary and paid. I've found a few questions on here about it, but they don't have their own tag. There seem to be a few people who are familiar with it around, but you'll have to attract them. I would start by renaming the question to something more useful.

Comment: Can't put the solution in here anymore, so a comment will have to do. Interesting I didn't get notified, because I use Aestiva's HTML OS a lot and have dealt with this issue many times. As the OP already pointed out, this has to do with the fact that HTMLOS is 32-bit. So if you want this to work on a new server, you need to make sure to install the 32-bit library. This may be different between OS-es.. there's another command for non-CENTOS machines, just FYI. Oh, and the question does NOT have the answers in that link in the blue box at the top...